# Right Trimming Binary Data in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

**Scenario:**

I am inserting a string into a binary field (CONTEXT_INFO) and then later attempting to pull it out and convert it back to a string.  When I do, the resulting string has a length of 128 because it has trailing null characters.

**Example:**

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @binary VARBINARY(128)

SET @string = 'abcdefg'
SET @binary = CONVERT(VARBINARY(128), @string) --0x61626364656667000000...
SET CONTEXT_INFO @binary
SET @binary = CONTEXT_INFO()

-- I would like to change the following line so it trims trailing null chars
SET @string = CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), @binary)

SELECT
    @binary AS [binary],
    DATALENGTH(@binary) AS [binary.Length], --128 as expected
    @string AS [string],
    DATALENGTH(@string) AS [string.Length] --This is 128, but I need it to be 7
```

**Question:**

How can I trim the trailing null characters when I convert the binary field to a string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this, `works on Sql-Server 2008.` Here is [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/7512).

Please note that I am assuming that the original string has NOT got Char(0) in it as this could simply replace it even from the original string.

```
-- I would like to change the following line so it trims trailing null chars
SET @string = CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), @binary)
SET @string = REPLACE(@string, Char(0),'')
```

Comment: do you think it would be better to replace `SUBSTRING(@string, 127, 1)` with `CHAR(0)`?

Answer (score 4):

Here was my solution. I went this way because of what CONTEXT_INFO makes the value look like (pads to the right).

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @binary VARBINARY(128)

SET @string = 'abcdefg'
SET @string = REPLICATE(CHAR(0),128-LEN(@string))+@string
SET @binary = CONVERT(VARBINARY(128), @string)
SET CONTEXT_INFO @binary
SET @binary = CONTEXT_INFO()

SET @string = CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), REPLACE(@binary,CHAR(0),''))

SELECT
    @binary AS [binary],
    DATALENGTH(@binary) AS [binary.Length],
    @string AS [string],
    DATALENGTH(@string) AS [string.Length]
```

Comment: Oh god thank you.  I've been filling up my database with nulls to the right.  I had played with CASTing the CONTEXT_INFO, but CONVERT did the trick.  YAY!

Answer (score 2):

For the record, this will trim the trailing 0x00 and leave the 0x00 in place if they happen in the middle of the data:

```
cast(substring(CONTEXT_INFO(), 1, len(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONTEXT_INFO(), 0x20, 0x21), 0x00, 0x20))) as varbinary(128))
```

This gives a result as a varbinary, if you want a string, remove the outer cast

Most of the other solutions either end up removing the 0x00 in the middle, or changing it to a 0x20.

Answer (score 0):

Converting from `nvarchar(x)` to `varbinary(x)` back to `nvarchar(x)` will always round-trip correctly. The core issue described here occurs because `SELECT CONTEXT_INFO()` always returns 128 bytes, regardless of the length of the varbinary source used to set `CONTEXT_INFO`.

There are two workarounds.

**First workaround**: starting in SQL Server 2016, [`sp_set_session_context`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt605113.aspx) may be used to set the vastly superior [`session_context`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt590806.aspx).

**Second workaround**: `context_info` can be retrieved from [`sys.dm_exec_sessions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176013.aspx) in the way `CONTEXT_INFO()` *should* work. This query will return the `context_info` associated with the current connection:

```
SELECT context_info FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions WHERE session_id = @@SPID
```

Here's a comparison of the two retrieval methods in SSMS:

```
SET CONTEXT_INFO 0x010200340056;
GO

SELECT CONTEXT_INFO(); -- 0x0012003400560000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
SELECT context_info FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions WHERE session_id = @@SPID; -- 0x001200340056

SET CONTEXT_INFO 0x;
GO

SELECT CONTEXT_INFO(); -- NULL
SELECT context_info FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions WHERE session_id = @@SPID; -- 0x
```

**Caveat**: Setting `CONTEXT_INFO` should be executed in a batch separate from retrieving `context_info` via `sys.dm_exec_sessions` (as seen above via the SSMS batch-separator `GO`).