# SQL Server 2008 R2 Len function returns fixed value irrespective of value (from a view)

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to get the length of a field in a view from a SQL Server 2008 R2 database belonging to a 3rd party product. [I cannot access the tables directly and I don't have access to the definition of the view, so i don't know how this column is derived or query the tables]. This below query -

```
Select Len(Col1) from MyView
```

always returns 32 for all rows, irrespective of datalength.

So i tried these -

```
Select Len(Ltrim(Rtrim(Col1))) , Len(Convert(Varchar,Col1)) , Len(Convert(Varchar(16),Col1)) from MyView
```

it is returning 32,30,16 for all rows. Is anyone aware of this behavior ? I think it might be because they are deriving the column from somewhere else, but this behavior makes no sense to me [unless i am missing something obvious?]

Comment: What does `SELECT SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(Col1,'BaseType'), SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(Col1,'MaxLength') FROM MyView` return?

Comment: Hi @Nick.McDermaid, It is returning Varchar,32. Hope it helps.

Comment: Based on your description I can only assume the all 32 characters are used in the field. What kind of `datalength` values are you getting? I suggest this is a better query to analyse the data: `SELECT Col1, '[' + Col1 + ']', LEN(Col1), LEN(RTrim(LTrim(Col1))), DATALENGTH(Col1) FROM MyView`

Comment: Hi @Nick.McDermaid, Found the issue. it was because of Null characters in the data. I have posted my analysis in the answer below. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha! found the issue, It appears that this column has been converted from Varbinary data type. So [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162672/right-trimming-binary-data-in-sql-server) helped me to solve the issue -

```
Select Len(Replace(Col1,char(0),'')) from MyView
```

gives me the result I want.